# How can i get current Index using for each loop in javascript and update into realtime database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with javascript also am a newbie in js so actually, I want to  get the current index and then update a specific field to the realtime if somebody helps me out I will thankful to him here is my script where I fetch the data in realtime firebase and I put my value inside inner HTML format so I want when user press specific buttons its pending data update to booked.

```js
userDataRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot, index) {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val());
    key = childSnapshot.key;
    userid = childSnapshot.val().userid;
    var carid = childSnapshot.val().carid;
    var imageload = childSnapshot.val().imgurl;
    var loadfirstname = childSnapshot.val().userfirstname;
    var loadcarname = childSnapshot.val().carname;
    var loadlastname = childSnapshot.val().userlastname;
    var loadphonenumber = childSnapshot.val().phoneNumber;
    var loaddropoffadd = childSnapshot.val().dropoffaddress;
    var loadpickupadd = childSnapshot.val().pickupaddress;
    loadprice = childSnapshot.val().price;


    var appenddata =
      '<div class="container rounded"  style="background-color: #00829E" id="datalist">' +


      '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-12">' +
      '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-4 mt-2 mb-2 ml-2">' +
      '<div class="container rounded"style="background-color: #efefef">' +
      '<center>' +
      '<img src="' + imageload + '" id="loadimage" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">' +
      '</center>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +

      '<div class="col-md-6 mt-2 mb-2">' +
      '<div class="container rounded para">' +
      '<h5 id="loadcarname">' + loadcarname + '</h5>' +
      '<p id="loadfirstname">First Name: ' + loadfirstname + '</p>' +
      '<p id="loadlastname">Last Name: ' + loadlastname + '</p>' +
      '<p id="loadphone">Phone Number: ' + loadphonenumber + '</p>' +
      '<p id="loadpickup">Pickup Address: ' + loadpickupadd + '</p>' +
      '<p id="loaddropoff">Dropoff Address: ' + loaddropoffadd + '</p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +

      '<div class="col-md-2"></div>' +

      '</div>' +


      '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-4"></div>' +
      '<div class="col-md-4"></div>' +
      '<div class="col-md-2 para1 mt-2">' +
      '<p id="loadprice">Price:' + loadprice + ' Sum/Day</p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-md-2 mb-3">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm rounded-pill check"  id="approvebutton" value ="Booked" onclick="myFunction(this.value)"  aria-pressed="true">Approve</button>' +
      '</div>' +

      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
    $("#listshow").append(appenddata);



  });
});
```

when user press the button I call function named `Myfunction` I just want to update specific id in that function

my function name script

```js
function myFunction(value) {
  approvecar = document.getElementById('loadprice').value;

  firebase.database.ref("carBooking/" + userid).update({
    status: ""
  });
}
```

[image: this is my realtime db picture I want to update current user update status]

Comment: IDs need to be unique.

Comment: yeah it's unique I fetch user-id also

Comment: `myFunction` argument is `value` but you're trying to use `userid`..

Comment: yeah actually my idea is that I set button value by default booked and give onclick function name My function so inside this function I want to get the current user id so I can update my default value "Booked"

Comment: That's fine. Just change `firebase.database.ref("carBooking/" + userid).update({` to `firebase.database.ref("carBooking/" + value).update({`

Comment: Yeah I try this before I post it here but this thing not work for me if I update this which you said it's update only last one and I have 3 user data I want specific user update the status when I click button on Approved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to write a value in the database, you need to know the complete path to that node. Right now, you know what value to write, but you've lost information about what key (the `-M....` value) to write it to.

So you'll need to pass the key of the item the user clicked on, from your HTML into the `myFunction` function.

The simplest way to do that is something like:

```
'<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm rounded-pill check"  id="approvebutton" value ="Booked" 
onclick="myFunction(\''+key+'\', this.value)" //  is changed
aria-pressed="true">Approve</button>' +
```

*There may be some syntax problems in this part as I'm having a hard time parsing your HTML construction code.*

Now that you're passing both the key and the value, you can update the correct node with:

```
function myFunction(key, value) {
  approvecar = document.getElementById('loadprice').value;

  firebase.database.ref("carBooking").child(key).update({
    status: ""
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for correcting me and your time now I get my current user value but the problem is when I run this on console.log it shows me this Uncaught ReferenceError: MSCPszMrkQ7ZANocKgZ is not defined.. can you please tell me will be thankful to you

Comment: Updated the code, which wasn't quoting the key. I highly recommend spending some time on learning how to troubleshoot syntax errors like this yourself though, as reading the code and error in the browser should make it much easier to parse than the string concatenation we're dealing with here.